# How to find the optimal trail in linear cryptanalysis

Tags: cryptanalysis, linear-cryptanalysis

I'm reading and implementing this [tutorial](http://www.cs.bc.edu/%7Estraubin/crypto2017/heys.pdf), the author explains everything pretty clearly, the only thing I'm missing is how he decides which trail to use (pg. 12). I understand that one should prefer trails with the least amount of active S-Box and maximize the bias of the trail (in fact, finding the optimal trail seems to be the most important step when trying to apply linear cryptanalysis to a symmetric encryption algorithm).

It seems to me like some sort of dynamic programming problem, but I wonder if there is a general algorithm to solve the problem of finding the optimal trail (or at least, a series of candidate trails).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People use Matsui's "Best Path Search Algorithm" which is indeed a dynamic programming approach. The resource costs hard to anticipate and so branch and bound variations are employed in practice.

A skeletal outline can be found on slides 14-17 of [Matsui's retrospective talk on linear cryptanalysis at Asicrypt 2018](https://asiacrypt.iacr.org/2018/files/SLIDES/MONDAY/Z411/Asiacrypt2018_Matsui_Public.pdf).

A more formal description and some variants can be found in Ji, Zhang and Ding's 2019 paper "[Improving Matsui’s Search Algorithm for the Best Differential/Linear Trails and its Applications for DES, DESL and GIFT](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/1190.pdf)"

Answer (score 1):

Matsui's method is the classical one, but nowadays the trend is towards MILP/SAT/SMT-based search. The correctness of the trail and its link with the transition probability is encoded into the system and is then optimized to minimize the total probability (for SAT/SMT binary search can be used, for MILP the optimization is native).

Some examples (most of the research is for differential attacks though, but it typically translated to linear attacks):

- [Accelerating the Search of Differential and Linear Characteristics with the SAT Method](https://eprint.iacr.org/2021/213)
- [MILP-Based Automatic Search Algorithms for Differential and Linear Trails for Speck](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/407)
- [Improving the MILP-based Security Evaluation Algorithm against Differential/Linear Cryptanalysis Using A Divide-and-Conquer Approach](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/019)
- [Revisiting AES Related-Key Differential Attacks with Constraint Programming](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/139)

Comment: I thinks this answer needs some links to those...

Comment: SAT=satisfiability, MILP = mixed integer linear programming, SMT? Please don't use undefined acryonyms that are not so common and reduce an answer's usefullness